# Opcache and shared memory issue

Tags: php, cache, shared-memory

I installed zend_opcache on my server box , but I can not increase `opcache.memory_consumption` over 1600 . (example : 2048) . after increase following error occur in server :

```
Fatal Error Fatal Error Unable to allocate shared memory segment of 2147483648 bytes: mmap: No space left on device (28)Unable to allocate shared memory segment of 2147483648 bytes: mmap: No space left on device
```

any idea to solve issue ?

****Update : ****

[image: free-g]

Comment: Add output of "free -g" and "ipcs -l" please.

Comment: sorry , nobody can help ?

Comment: Is `memory_limit` set appropriately in your php.ini ?  Defaults to 128mb. http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit

Comment: Yes , I even increased it to 512 and 2048M , but not help .